# spring-boot-thin-layout is not found in maven repo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have this in my pom

```
   <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.26.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

but maven could not find it.

Proxy is turned off.

Other plugins are fine.

Comment: https://search.maven.org/search?q=spring-boot-thin-layout ?

Comment: Here, exactly like yours, runs fine. What is the maven message ?